# Python_terraform lib does not apply init command during the initial start of the code

Tags: python-3.x, terraform, terraform-provider-oci

I am trying to invoke the terraform code using the python_terraform module but the issue is whenever I am trying to run the code for the first time it does not invoke the "terraform init" automatically, I have to manually execute the "terraform init" on the respective folder and then run my python code. Post that the second time the code runs perfectly there is no blockage in that.

Code Block:

```
tf = Terraform(working_dir='Terraform_Infra_code')

tfinitresp = tf.init(no_color=IsFlagged, refresh=False, capture_output=True)
print(''.join(tfinitresp[1]))
tfplanresp = tf.plan(no_color=IsFlagged, refresh=False, capture_output=True)
print(''.join(tfplanresp[1]))
tfapplyresp = tf.apply(no_color=IsFlagged, refresh=False, capture_output=True, skip_plan=True)
print(''.join(tfapplyresp[1]))
cmd = 'terraform output -json > /Downloads/temp/output.txt'
os.system(cmd)
```

Please let me know if I am missing out anything, all suggestions are welcome

Comment: From the documentation of `python_terraform` it is really not suppose to run `init` automatically ... so there's no issue ... https://github.com/beelit94/python-terraform/blob/develop/python_terraform/terraform.py